# Singing in pitch problem

Tags: voice, tone, pitch, voice-training

I'm a guitar player and never was able to sing. Well, to be honest I never wanted or tried to sing. But for 2 months already I'm trying to start singing. The main problem is that I can't produce the note I'm hearing from my mouth. I can start flat and then rise it to the pitch or start sharp and lower the note to the pitch but I cannot identify the note from start. I feel that I'm not in pitch. I'm not tone deaf, because I tune my guitar everyday with my ears, I can figure out music on guitar with ear(although sometime it takes long, but I still can). The tone problem is only in my singing. Do you have any tips? How can I get better at singing? Only thing I found useful yet is just singing. I can sing and play Space Oddity 50% right(a month ago I couldn't even hit a single note correctly). But are there any other tips?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I struggle with the same thing, and have made progress by singing the notes I play as I play them to hear them together and adjusting like you say. Then I play intervals, and sing them while playing, once again adjusting. Last, I'll start trying to sing the note or interval from memory and play it after, i.e. sing the root, play the root, adjust, sing the 5th, play the 5th adjust. It has made a difference, and has started to help my ability to play melodies by ear at the same time. I'm not a vocal coach or singer, so didn't want to assume this was a good answer, hence the comment!

Comment: It took me at least five years to teach myself to do what you are saying you can't do after two months. For at least 15 years my pitch sense and ability to sing on key steadily improved. It takes a long time to learn to do anything well.

Comment: I know that it will take a long time. But it will take even longer if you don't know how to improve. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to learn most things is immersion.Jump right in and get on with it. You tune your guitar by ear? Not a tuner? Good! Sing those notes as you do it. They're all pretty well in your range, I guess.

Play a random note on guitar. Sing it. Although a better way is to think and sing in a particular key. Take a tune you play - it'll be in a key. Play the first note, sing it, then sing the next *before* playing it. gradually include more notes to be sung before played.

Try whistling instead! And play a note randomly, sing it, then think what the note two frets higher sounds like, and sing that; three frets higher, one fret lower. You probably get that idea.

Take a song with words (most have them...) and sing those words to associate them with pitches. Use 'lah', but not exclusively. 'Doo', 'baa', 'mee', 'wah' - all sorts of different sounds. Some will get you to the target note more easily - you need to find which. And all the time, you're just getting on with it.

You may be one of the folks who pitch a 4th /5th away from the right note. Don't know how that works, but heard it many times. If that's the case, then you will be made aware, and thus can do something about it.

Last idea - go to a teacher! One who has loads of experience with guys with your problem. Even a couple of lessons should put you on the right track. Keep singing!

Answer (score 0):

Your voice is probably Baritone or Bass. You said you can sing Space Oddity (David Bowie). The lowest note he sings is B2 on piano. This is low af. Most songs from 19xx until today have a vocal range between A3 and G4. It's a struggle for baritones and bass singers.

I suggest you having private lessons with a professional vocal teacher. It will not only help you in this issue, but also prevent you from getting used to common mistakes and ruining your voice in long term. Remember that, unlike guitar strings, you can not change your vocal strings in a music shop.